# Transforming multiple sets of coordinates in attribute table by name of field using PyQGIS

Tags: coordinate-system, pyqgis, fields-attributes, coordinates, epsg

I have a script that takes a set of points and computes the distance to nearby geographic points taken from OSM data. The output layer is the point layer with new fields showing the distance to, name and coordinates of the data points. As shown below, each data point has the pattern, {distance, name, x, y}, with the id of the point at the start of each feature.

I need to transform the x and y field for each data point to EPSG:4326 (long lat) for use in an external WMS that doesn't support EPSG:3006 coordinates.

[image: attribute table example]

What's the best approach here? The attributes are taken from the processing script 'join attributes by nearest' like this:

```py
for point in INPUT['points'].getFeatures():
        
    uuid = point['objekt_id'] # save objekt_id of point for adding to OUTPUT
        
    PT_LYR = QgsVectorLayer('Point?crs=epsg:3006', 'OUTPUT', 'memory')
    prov00 = PT_LYR.dataProvider()
    prov00.addFeature(point)

    for key in DATA.keys():
            
        # add the fields that are used for every data point
        attrs = [
                    QgsField('Distance to ' + key, QVariant.Int), # distance to target
                    QgsField('Name of ' + key, QVariant.String), # OSM name of target
                    QgsField('x of ' + key, QVariant.String),
                    QgsField('y of ' + key, QVariant.String)
                ]
        prov.addAttributes(attrs)
            
        # find closest point of target dataset to origin
        OUTPUT[key] = processing.run('native:joinbynearest', 
        {
            "INPUT": PT_LYR,
            "INPUT_2": DATA[key],
            "FIELDS_TO_COPY": "",
            "DISCARD_NONMATCHING": 'True',
            "PREFIX": "joined_",
            "NEIGHBORS": 1,
            "MAX_DISTANCE": 10000,
            "OUTPUT": QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        })["OUTPUT"]
            
            
    # Add the data of closest points from all datasets in use to output layer
    # Output is a point located on the same origin but containing data with from target points
    outputFeats = [next(OUTPUT[k].getFeatures()) for k in OUTPUT.keys() if k != "pts"]
        
    feat = QgsFeature()
    feat.setGeometry(point.geometry())
    
    #Distance to nearest hub process returns distance and name of chosen field in target point
    attributes = list(sum([(f['distance'], f['joined_name'], f['nearest_x'], f['nearest_y']) for f in outputFeats],()))
    feat.setAttributes([uuid] + attributes)
    prov.addFeature(feat)
    del feat
```

To clarify what my goal is, this is what the output should look like:

[image: transformed attribute table]

I currently use 8 different data points that I calculate the distance to, so doing this in the field calculator for each field would be very inefficient. Is there perhaps some way to transform the content of fields starting with 'x of ..'? Or is it better to do the transformation in the script when creating the output feature?

Comment: Try one Refactor fields

Comment: You seem to have presented part of one line of code but not a code snippet.